# Append HTML with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML

```
<section>
  <div>
     <p>{{item}}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

controller.js

```
(function () {
   var ctrl = function ($scope){
        $scope.item = "test";
   }
}());
```

This is my team's project. I cannot change how it is set up. The problem I am trying to solve is inserting the $scope.item into the html. How could I do this?

Answer (score 8):

I added an id _item in section.

```
<section id="_item">
  <div>
     <p>{{item}}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Write this below code inside the controller.js file.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('_item')).append($compile("<div>
     <p>{{item}}</p>
  </div>")($scope));
```

Note: add dependency $compile.

I think this will help you.

Comment: I think this will work, but how could I connect the two files? I cannot just do ng-controller="ctrl"

Comment: $scope.bindHtml =function(){angular.element(document.getElementById('_item')).append($compile("<div>
     <p>{{item}}</p>
  </div>")($scope));  };    // call the function in ng-init="bindHtml" in the html page.                                    <div ng-controller="[YOURCONTROLLER NAME]" ng-init="bindHtml()"><section id="_item"></section></div>

Comment: What is the significance of doing ($scope) at the end??

Comment: Dear Bikal Nepal $compile recompile the appended HTML code and apply $scope

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the most basic ways to do it.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('myController', function($scope){
     $scope.item = 'test'
});


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
     <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

UPDATE

[app.js]

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

[controller.js]

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
         $scope.item = 'test'
    });
```

Comment: I understand this, but I have to do it from the controller.js file

Comment: Please see my update. Include both these js files in to your html.

Comment: In your html, `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

Add `ng-controller="your_controller_name"` to your HTML.

```
<section ng-controller="myController">
  <div>
     <p>{{item}}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

The title of the answer might be missleading. If you really want to append HTML with Angular JS, I think what you need is the ng-bind-html directive

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

your html code should be something like

```
<section>
  <div>
   <p ng-bind-html="item"></p>
  </div>
 </section>
```

the following conf in your controller

```
.controller('myController','$sce' function($scope, $sce){
 $scope.item = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div> this is really appending HTML using AngularJS </div>");
 });
```