# Append a HTML string in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my code, I am trying to append a string

```
var _html = '<div class="env-type-text">${self.environmentType}</div>';
```

to a div that I can get via  a className

```
var _el = document.getElementsByClassName("domain-wks-env-type-icon")[0];
```

Now when I append the string to the div by

```
angular.element(_el).append($compile(_html)($scope));
```

It shows `self.environmentType` **not it's value.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what is going on here, but you append strings from your controller/directive like this: `{{$prefix.environmentType}}`. Are you possibly running ng-metadata? That would make things easier for me (and you)

Comment: `{{$prefix.environmentType}}` not showing me anything @Joel

Comment: I think you are trying to mix good ol' javascript with angularjs. 
You could use the ng-bind-html directive (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) or even do what you want directly in the template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append HTML with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348720/append-html-with-angularjs)

Comment: @StrugglingCoder no, i mean, your prefix. Which seems to be `self` in this example. Also, if all you want to do is to compile html, you can do  `<p ng-bind-html="self.environmentType"></p>` and use the build in functionality for this.

Comment: @Joel Yes I used self only

Comment: Please post your controller / directive code...